# Get Windows 10 icon on the taskbar without NX support?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, cpu, windows-10-preview

I have an old Pentium 4 PC running Windows 7. The CPU doesn't support [NX](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/what-is-pae-nx-sse2).
I have seen some methods for disabling the NX check given a Windows 8, 8.1 or 10 Technical Preview ISO.
But I want to get Windows 10 for free, and for this reason I have to be able to get the Get Windows 10 icon shown on my taskbar.

How can I do to make the *Get Windows 10* icon appear on my taskbar, even though my PC doesn't have support for NX?

Comment: the free license only works for the device and win 8x and win10 require NX, so you can't install win10 on it and can't sue the free license.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I assume you mean use not sue?  Even if you got past this check its unlikely Windows 10 would even function on your system.

Comment: I know, but I have seen videos on YouTube where people install the Technical Preview without any problem

Comment: post a link to such a video.

Comment: https://youtu.be/II8OiGm7h2s